# Using the Class itself as a Method

Tags: ruby

Today I came across the [`Pathname`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html) class in Ruby and noticed that you could directly call the class itself as a method (which would basically return a new instance):

```
Pathname("some/path")
# => #<Pathname:some/path>
```

I've been trying to replicate the same thing with my `CustomClass` but haven't been successful. I don't know what these methods are called and I can't find any Ruby code that gives me an idea on how to do this. **My Question is how do I use the Class name as method?**

Things I've tried so far:

- Defining `self.self()`
- Defining `self.class()`
- Using the `class << self` syntax
- Googling - But it just returns comparisons of class methods vs instance methods

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't using the class itself. This is calling a method in `Kernel` with the same name as the class. It's generally discouraged to do it yourself as you pollute almost all objects with new methods and leads to confusion (as you already see).

[Here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.3/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Kernel.html) is the documentation for the method. There are a few others like `Array`, `Hash`, `String`, [etc](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Kernel.html#method-i-Array).

Comment: Hmmm, interesting. So the only reason of defining it was to create a shortcut?

Comment: @Sheharyar, yes. And most people don't use the capital letter methods so it's not that useful anyway.

Comment: I use [`Kernel#Integer`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer) a lot when parsing user input and find it very useful.

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is a **conversion method** to coerce the input to the instance of the class.

It is not a method of the class itself, but a method in `Kernel` module. So in order to be able to use the form of `MyClass(value)` you should add the method to [`Kernel`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Kernel.html) module:

```
module Kernel
  def Foo(value)
    # you can implement any logic here
    value.is_a?(Foo) ? value : Foo.new(value)
  end
  module_function :Foo
end

class Foo
  def initialize(bar)
    @bar = bar
  end
end

baz = Foo('bar')
#=> #<Foo:0x007fd4e5070370 @bar="bar">
Foo(baz)
#=> #<Foo:0x007fd4e5070370 @bar="bar">
baz == Foo(baz)
#=> true
```

Comment: In addition, you should call `module_function :Foo` after defining the method in `Kernel`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a class call, but a shortcut. And the trickiest part - it was defined for a `Kernel` module to be available everywhere in the form as you just specified.

Please proceed to the link of the [official docs](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.3/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/index.html). There you can see, that requiring a `Pathname` module, it extend `Kernel` module to add the method of the same name.

To be honest, I strongly recommend against extending `Kernel` with your own method. Or at least to use [refinements](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html)